# I did alter table by hiveql. Then It didn't work to show table by spark-sql. ERROR : Path does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I did alter table by HiveQL.

```
"ALTER TABLE new_law_area_2 RENAME TO law_area"
```

Then I intended to show my table by spark-sql.

```
"SELECT * FROM law_area LIMIT 10"
```

But, it didn't work... with this error.

`org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`

```
17/04/18 14:17:47 ERROR SparkSQLDriver: Failed in [select * from law_area limit 10]
org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://dmlab/apps/hive/warehouse/dimension.db/new_law_area_2;
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4882)
    at org.spark_project.guava.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.apply(LocalCache.java:4898)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionCatalog.lookupRelation(HiveSessionCatalog.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:479)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$8.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLDriver.run(SparkSQLDriver.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.processCmd(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver$.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver.main(SparkSQLCLIDriver.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:745)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

How can I solve this problem?

plz... my all tables didn't work in this way...

I want to use spark-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try -

```
alter table law_area set location 'hdfs://dmlab/apps/hive/warehouse/dimension.db/law_area'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. I just wanted to add, if DuduMarkovitz's answer does not work for you,

```
ALTER TABLE law_area SET SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'path'='hdfs://dmlab/apps/hive/warehouse/dimension.db/law_area')
```

worked for me.